# Issue calling JSON object property value with Jquery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to call an object property value and append it to the div "file-path-info". The function that appends JSON data to "file-size-info" works. What am I doing wrong with my second statement?

My JSON data:

```
{"maxFileSize" : "10 MB", "fileList" :  [{"fileName" : "1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat", "href" : "../Images/1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat.jpg"}]}
```

HTML and JavaScript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="file-size-info"></div>
<div id="file-path-info"></div>

<script>

    $.getJSON('http://localhost/MISREST/helpdocs', function (data) {
  $.each( JSON.parse(data), function ( key, val ) {
    if (key == "maxFileSize") {$("#file-size-info").append(val);};

      if (key == "fileList") {$("#file-path-info").append(["fileList"]["href"]);};

  });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `["fileList"]["href"]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
if (key == "fileList") {
   $("#file-path-info").append(val[0]["href"]);
};
```

assuming you only have one value in `fileList`, if not then you need to loop over the values.

as for the `fileList` key , `val` gives you

```
[
  {
    "fileName": "1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat",
    "href": "../Images/1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat.jpg"
  }
]
```

and then you need to extract href from the first object.

Comment: Note: This is assuming OP wants to show only the first element in the `fileList` array. And not the entire list of files.

Comment: In the second case he should be mapping over the array values, I will update the answer in case the OP comes back with a updated question

Answer (score 1):

```
if (key == "maxFileSize") {$("#file-size-info").append(val);};
```

In that block of code `maxFileSize` is the key and `val` is the value of that property (the string `10 MB`).

Following that pattern, when `fileList` is the key, `val` would be the value of that property: `[{"fileName" : "1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat", "href" : "../Images/1_Exterior Cabinet_Cabinet C_Economizer_Econ_Exhaust_Gas Heat.jpg"}]` (an array containing a single item that is an object).

You'll need to index the array to get the item at index 0 (the only item) and grab the value of that object's `href` property in order to use it:

```
if (key == "fileList") {$("#file-path-info").append(val[0].href);};
```